# How can I read zfs spa stat

Tags: linux, zfs

In this [pr](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/9789/files#diff-4e654614c4ba03084ef81196569b823e6603d38b92f1434e9f00f943676157ff), add some spa stat like `simple_trim_bytes_failed` , but how can I read these stat ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values end up in the I/O statistics. You can find them at `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/$POOLNAME/iostats`.

Looks like this for me:

```
34 1 0x01 18 4896 11524202364 3620409432155645
name                            type data
trim_extents_written            4    0
trim_bytes_written              4    0
trim_extents_skipped            4    0
trim_bytes_skipped              4    0
trim_extents_failed             4    0
trim_bytes_failed               4    0
autotrim_extents_written        4    8284089
autotrim_bytes_written          4    1235386707968
autotrim_extents_skipped        4    11839369
autotrim_bytes_skipped          4    109900025856
autotrim_extents_failed         4    0
autotrim_bytes_failed           4    0
simple_trim_extents_written     4    0
simple_trim_bytes_written       4    0
simple_trim_extents_skipped     4    0
simple_trim_bytes_skipped       4    0
simple_trim_extents_failed      4    0
simple_trim_bytes_failed        4    0
```

Dunno what the first line does, but you can probably find out relatively easily by reading the ZFS source code.